# Как найти сумму цифр в строке?

Tags: python, строки

Ввод:
211
212
121
111
111

Необходимо вывести сумму цифр в строке.

Вывод:
3
4
4
3
3

Answer (score 1):

первое что нужно - написать алгоритм словами и на бумажке :)

когда возникают сложности - решайте в лоб, красоту потом наводить можно

алгоритм:

1. разбить строку на слова и занести их в список (используется метод `.split()`)
2. пройтись по всем словам в списке
3. каждое слово представить как список букв (достаточно пройтись по слову через `for`)
4. преобразовать буквы в цифры (используется функция `int()`)
5. сложить цифры (например с помощью функции `sum()`)
6. вывести результат на экран

вроде все просто?

P.S.

кстати в примере вывод должен быть `4 5 4 3 3`

P.P.S.

ну а потом, если требуется, весь этот код легко сворачивается в 1 строчку